# Adding a single string from an array list to TextView

Tags: java, android, arrays

My Code: starts with after onCreate Override then the the bottom portion is my ArrayAdapter. Im trying to add individual strings from the array to a TextView. When I run the app it puts all the strings in the array on every TextView it makes. Thanks for taking a look.

```
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mMyStringArrayArray());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

...

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, strings);


        }

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
     if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
        }                       

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_list_linearLayout);
        TextView[] strings = new TextView[mMyStringArray.size()];


        for (int i = 0; i < mMyStringArray().size(); i++) {

            // Create TextView
            strings[i] = new TextView(getActivity());
            strings[i].setText(mMyStringsArray(i));
            strings[i].setId(i + 5);
            mLinearLayout.addView(strings[i]);



        }


        return convertView;
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getView()` is called once for each item in your `Adapter`. So, with your `for loop`, that is running through each item in `mMyStringArray` for every item in your `Adapter`. Try instead to use `position` to get the element you need. Something like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
  if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
    }                       

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_list_linearLayout);
    TextView[] strings = new TextView[mMyStringArray.size()];

        // Create TextView
        strings[position] = new TextView(getActivity());
        strings[position].setText(mMyStringsArray(i));
        strings[position].setId(position + 5);
        mLinearLayout.addView(strings[position]);
    }
    return convertView;
  }
```

Something like that should work. However, since you have the `layout` it would be much easier to just create a `TextView` inside your `LinearLayout` of `my_list.xml` and use that.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
  if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
    }                       

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_list_linearLayout);
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.someID) //where someID is the id you give the TextView in your layout file


        tv.setText(mMyStringsArray(position));
        tv.setId(position + 5);  // Shouldn't need this now
    }
    return convertView;
  }
```

I also suggest watching [The world of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=d60XU8b5Msb4yAG44IDoBQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=ttAZXyfxwiobhpcIvxRz_w&bvm=bv.62577051,d.aWc)

Comment: Thank You very much. Im new to this and learning new things everyday.